# c# gui - navigate between forms

Tags: c#, forms, user-interface, back-button

I'm programming c# GUI and I have 2 forms.

`Form1` is my main form, and it has a button to open `form2`.

When the button in `form1` is being clicked, I hide `form1`, create a new object of `form2` and show `form2`.

I have a back button in `form2`. I want the behavior of this button to close `form2`, and show again the hidden `form1`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Have your `form1` subscribe to the [`VisibleChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visiblechanged.aspx) event of `form2` and act accordingly. It will have to "remember" whether `form2` is visible or hidden (or query it directly).

The alternatives are:

Your `form2` will need a reference to `form1`.

This can be done in a number of ways - passing it in a constructor parameter, adding a property and assigning `form1` to it.

Either of these ways will tightly couple these forms to each other (bad thing).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
     Form1.Visible = true;
     Form1.Activate();
```

And then in the Form1 *VisibleChanged* Event you simply write

```
     Form2.Close();
```

Comment: There's no `Activate` method exposed by the `Form` class, that takes another `Form` as parameter.

Comment: I'm sorry I wrote on the OnLoad event but i meant VisibleChanged Event since your form is already loaded it won't execute that part if you only change the visibility of the form.

Comment: Youre  right @ebb  I was thinking about the `AddOwnedForm` method wich isn't exactly used for the same reasons ^^ i'll update my answer thanks

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered if I fully answered to it :)